# PHP upload not working due to size limitation

Tags: post, file-upload, upload, php

my php.ini values

```
upload_max_size = 14000M
post_max_size = 14000M
```

if i increase value more than 14000M, $_POST can't be accessed and using that value i can upload a file of 1.5GB only and **can't upload a file of 2.14GB**.

Here i have three questions

1. What should i do so $_POST array also keep in working and i can also
   upload a file of 2.14 GB.
2. Why $_POST is not working when i exceed
   value more than 14000M
3. 14000M should mean 14GB, isn't so? if so
   then why i can't upload file of 2.14GB

Comment: Just a side note: `$_POST` has nothing to do with file uploads

Comment: What is in your webserver and php logs?

Comment: What problem do you have exactly with larger files, time-outs, empty results, etc.?

Comment: is `allocated_memory_size` error occur ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found answer to my question after 2 days work.
This is a bug in PHP which allow us to put *_max_size = 14000M and don't allow us to upload a file of 14000MB.

Reference https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35578

We can't upload file for more than 2047MB, so following values are meaning less

```
upload_max_size = 14000M
post_max_size = 14000M
```

and should be converted to its maximum value like

```
upload_max_size = 2047M
post_max_size = 2047M
```

So now you can upload about 1.99GB File

Comment: this is what I told you in my answer... you could probably save some time had you used it :-)

Comment: anyway it doesn't make any sense to upload such large files - for this, you should use chunked upload, e.g. with plupload.

Answer (score 0):

THere is no only `upload_max_size` and `post_max_size` that affect on file upload. Check [this link](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php)

The most important is `memory_limit`. when you tring to upload big file, php run out memory

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck using G (Gigs) in my php.ini file:

upload_max_size = 3G

post_max_size = 3G

Not sure if this will help with the $_POST issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are much more limitations and pitfalls you have to check for, see oficial PHP documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Anyway, note that the 2G is also a limit of signed 32bit integer! So this problem might rise from some other limits unrelated to upload itself. Also, what is the maximum file size on the server filesystem? 2G is a limit on some systems.